# DataRow to bool casting

Tags: c#, casting, boolean, datarow

I have an xml file from which I read data in the unit test : `[DataSource]`
For the xml line : `<DataBool>true</DataBool>`, I try to read value by :

```
bool bData = (bool)TestContext.DataRow[4];
```

But it throws exception - invalid casting.What is the possible efficient solution?

Comment: what does the `TestContext.DataRow[4]` outputs?

Comment: It might be of type `bool?` instead of `bool` (question mark is not a typo), since the type from your source might actually be [`Nullable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Comment: What is the value of `TestContext.DataRow[4].GetType().ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no schema associated with it, then it's probably just a string.  If so, use `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse` to convert it from a string to a bool.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `int-tinyint` value in DB :

```py
int.Parse(dataRow["column_name"].ToString()) == 1 ? true : false
```

Comment: can you please explain what your bit of code does so it can help others with a similar issue ?